# Configuring Angular.JS ($interpolateProvider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to build an angular app so I can sort through paginated pages on my site, but am running into a little trouble.

## Problem / Problematic Code

**I need to change the interpolateProvider**, but can't really figure out how to insert it. My current framework runs it's own server side language where `{{ html }}` is reserved for it's own language, so following Angular's example, I used this code to swap the `{{ html }}` into `[[ html ]]`.

**Angular ($interpolateProvider); Swap**

*I have this implemented directly after defining my `app` var*

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {
     $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
     $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
}]);
```

---

## Issues / Attempted Solutions

Here's the issue I am running into, my website is reading the HTML before this interpolateProvider is changed, thus throwing a hand full of errors. Some things I've tried to remedy this:

• Moved `$iP` function into the `<head>` alone, directly after including the Angular.JS CDN. I don't believe this works though since it needs my app defined before swapping the `$iP`.

• Included my app functions JS file in before Angular, obvious why this one didn't work

• Included the `$iP` in my main functions JS, included into template directly after Angular

---

## Observations

It seems that it just can't define my app's directive, but I feel like this may be a part of a series of errors. I have the code running perfectly fine in a **[[JSFiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/2614/)** but can't repeat the success within my website.

This is the error my site is throwing:

> Error: Unknown provider: aProvider <- a
>       at Error (native)
>       at https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0/angular-1.0.0.js:2627:15
>       at Object.getService [as get] (https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0/angular-1.0.0.js:2755:39)
>       at https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0/angular-1.0.0.js:2632:45
>       at getService (https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0/angular-1.0.0.js:2755:39)
>       at invoke (https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0/angular-1.0.0.js:2773:13)
>       at Object.instantiate (https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0/angular-1.0.0.js:2805:23)
>       at https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0/angular-1.0.0.js:4619:24
>       at https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0/angular-1.0.0.js:4200:17
>       at forEach (https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0/angular-1.0.0.js:117:20)(anonymous function) @ angular-1.0.0.js:5525(anonymous function) @ angular-1.0.0.js:4659Scope.$apply @ angular-1.0.0.js:7851(anonymous function) @ angular-1.0.0.js:930invoke @ angular-1.0.0.js:2788bootstrap @ angular-1.0.0.js:928angularInit @ angular-1.0.0.js:904(anonymous function) @ angular-1.0.0.js:14322j @ jquery.min.js:2k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2n.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:2K @ jquery.min.js:2
>   multi:640 Object

Thanks for any, and all help everyone!

Comment: I might not completely follow your question, but do you yourself write the square brackets in your angular code, or have you just pasted that `$interpolateProvider` code in your config? `$interpolateProvider` does **NOT** transform your {{ expression }} into [[ expression ]], you have to do that 

Comment: Are you asking about my app's `html` where I need to call in Angular codes? Because within my app-directive, anytime I need to call some Angular I use `[[ ]]` and if I need to call my server's code I use `{{ }}`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
})
```

this is working in my project with laravel.

Comment: No dice, unfortunately.